# Float right android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

Unable to make a View in a linear layout float right. Below is my code. If layout_gravity aligns the view in its parent, then the third view(second ImageView in the below code) should be on the right, which is not the case. How to fix this?

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#456abc"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/arrow_down" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ABDEF" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@mipmap/arrow_right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please send an image of what you exactly want?

Comment: @DroidAks http://imgur.com/a/OXOkN Unable to add an image

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using a `RelativeLayout`:

**imageview left:**

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

**textview info:**

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

**imageview right:**

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

**layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#456abc" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="ABDEF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its not about if you would have 4th element. Image link has been provided that clearly tells that there are only 3 components and that should be spaced and arranged symmetrically.

Comment: Im only trying to explain how a linearlayout works and why gravity is different from float. The part about relative layout solves the problem.

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol: texview is still to the left. How do I fix that?

Comment: I think the text in your textalign is just aligned left. Try setting `android:gravity="left"` on your textview

Comment: I will add the full xml

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the below xml layout.

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#456abc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/arrow_down" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ABDEF" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@mipmap/arrow_right" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This did produce the output. If you could explain how to right align a view without this 'hack' it will be great. Not restricted to LinearLayout,

Comment: This is not a hack. android:layout_weight is the only way to get this type of view in LinearLayout. Or Else you can go with RelativeLayout.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#456abc"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/left"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_weight="0.3"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_weight="0.4"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ABDEF" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/right"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_weight="0.3"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try out this. Added ic_launcher image, you can add your own images.

Comment: This does not float the image right. It stretches all elements to fit the entire row.